# 127.0.0.1にアクセスが出来ない。

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos, nginx

CentOS7×nginx環境下のvpsでテストとしてnode.jsのhttpサーバを構築したのですが、[global ip address]:[port]では普通にアクセスできるものの、[127.0.0.1]:[port]ではアクセス出来ず気持ち悪いのでこちらに質問させて頂きました。

・node.jsのhttpサーバ

```
 var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(
        200,
        {
            'Content-Type':'text/html'
        }
    );// END writeHead
    res.end('<h1>Hello Node</h1>');
});//END createServer
server.listen(8080);
console.log('server started on xxxx');
```

・/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf設定

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name hoge.fuga.com（まだドメインとってません）;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server1.com;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/server1;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server2.com;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/server2;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server3.com;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/server3;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server4.com;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/server4;
  }
}
```

・/etc/nginx/nginx.conf設定（sereverディレクティブのみ抜粋）

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

nginx.confは特にいじってません。hostsファイルも特段いじってません。（バーチャルサーバーは追加）
virtual.confはリバースプロキシ設定しましたがちゃんと出来てる自信がありません。

・尚、参考になるかわかりませんがifconfigするとこんなのが出ます

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
```

どなたか詳しい方いましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 127.0.0.1で接続できないというアクセス元は、CentOS上のブラウザか何かでしょうか？

Comment: コマンドラインから`127.0.0.1`に対して`ping`を打った場合はどうなるのでしょうか。

Comment: CentOS上ではなく普通にローカルにインストールしたブラウザ（Chrome）のはずですが、アクセス元の調べ方がいまいち分からず曖昧な返答ですみません。@豚吐露

Comment: pingを打つと問題なく疎通しているようです。
ちなみに20回テストして以下の表示でした。↓
[20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19000ms] @cubick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1`は自分自身を指す特別なIP Addressです。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

おそらく、PCとSERVER(CentOS)をnetworkでつなぎ接続しようと思われてるのでしょうが、PCから`127.0.0.1`を指定するとPC自身を指すことになってしまいます。
特別な設定などをしていない限り、`127.0.0.1`で接続できるのは、HTTP serverであるSERVER自身からだけです。
自分自身を指すので、特別な設定などが行われていなければ、pingが通るのはそうだろうなぁ...という感じです。

---

一応、設定などでPCから`127.0.0.1`の指定があれば、SERVERに接続させることもできますが、あまりお勧めできません。

kt_shindoさんの環境や実現したいことなどが分かればもっと良い回答がつくかもしれません。
どうしても`127.0.0.1`で接続したいのであれば、詳しい環境や実現したいことを質問に追記すると良いと思います。
質問内容が大きく変わるのであれば、別の質問を作ってもらった方が良いかと思います。

Comment: 豚吐露さん
詳細ありがとうございます、勉強になりました。
Localhostにどうしても接続したいという訳でなくネット上で調べたnode.jsのhttpサーバの構成が→[server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1');]になっているケースが多かったのでwebブラウザで見れない＝不具合だと思っていました。
頂いた回答を読んで状況が飲み込めてスッキリしました。